# Maximum Daily Drawdown Graph - Not functioning correctly

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to map an MDD graph via Python using the same skeletal code which is prevalent in almost any google search. However, I am having difficulty creating a "smooth" line which represents the daily information.

It is as if it's depicting every single drawdown at maximum frequency? At first, I thought it was the duration of the time series, however, most examples I find have 10 - 20 years included in their daily data so I'm not really sure this is a valid problem?

If someone could pinpoint what I'm missing, this would be very helpful.

See code below and an example output:

```
# Maximum Daily Draw-Down
window = 252

roll_max = ew_daily.rolling(window, min_periods=1).max()

# Calculate daily draw-down from rolling 
daily_drawdown = (ew_daily/roll_max) - 1.0

# Calculate maximum daily draw-down
max_daily_drawdown = daily_drawdown.rolling(window, min_periods=1).min()

# Plot the results
daily_drawdown.plot()
max_daily_drawdown.plot()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: What exactly is wrong in this graph as presented?

Comment: The line on the graph is not aesthetically pleasing - a little overcrowded. I suppose I could just re-sample and annualise the data, but it continues to appear 'obtuse'.